# Graph API Facebook timeout

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cakephp

I have Facebook pages which I need to extract sum data every day(like,post,shar...), but I run my script hi got data for 2 or 3 page Facebook max and hi stoped with sum error

my script

```
include '../webroot/fb/facebook.php';
        //Get Facebook SDK Object
        $config = array(
                'appId'  => 'codeapl',
                'secret' => 'secret',
                'cookie' => true);
        $facebook = new Facebook($config);
        $this->Pag->recursive = -1;
        $pages=$this->Pag->find('all');
        foreach ($pages as $page)
        {
            //Info page
            $this->Pag->id=$page['Pag']['id'];
            $params = array('method' => 'fql.query',
                'query' =>  "SELECT pic FROM page WHERE page_id='".$page['Pag']['idpage']."'",);
            $result = $facebook->api($params);
            $this->request->data['Pag']['image']= $result[0]['pic'];
            $this->Pag->save($this->request->data);

            //Statistique
            $page_id=$page['Pag']['id'];
            $idpage=$page['Pag']['idpage'];
            $params = array('method' => 'fql.query',
                'query' =>  "SELECT fan_count,talking_about_count,pic FROM page WHERE page_id='$idpage'",);

            $result = $facebook->api($params);
            $this->loadModel('Statistique');
            $this->Statistique->create();
            $this->request->data['Statistique']['likes']= $result[0]['fan_count'];
            $this->request->data['Statistique']['talk']= $result[0]['talking_about_count'];
            $this->request->data['Statistique']['pag_id']= $page_id;

            $params = array('method' => 'fql.query',
                'query' => "select message,share_count,comments,likes from stream where source_id='$idpage' and is_published=1 limit 1000");
            $result = $facebook->api($params);
            $message=0;
            $comment=0;
            $shar=0;
            $like=0;
            foreach ($result as $value) 
            {
                $message++;
                $shar=$shar+$value['share_count'];
                if(isset ($value['likes']['count']))
                    $like=$like+$value['likes']['count'];
                $comment=$comment+$value['comments']['count'];
            }

            $this->request->data['Statistique']['posts']=$message;
            $this->request->data['Statistique']['likepost']=$like;
            $this->request->data['Statistique']['comments']=$comment;
            $this->request->data['Statistique']['char']=$shar;
            $this->Statistique->save($this->request->data);


            //pays
            $params = array('method' => 'fql.query',
                'query' =>  "SELECT value FROM insights WHERE
                    object_id='$idpage' AND metric='page_fans_country'
                    AND end_time=end_time_date('2013-04-14T07:00:00+0000') AND period=period('lifetime')",);
            $result = $facebook->api($params);
            $this->loadModel('Payspage');
            foreach ($result[0]['value'] as $key => $value)
            {
                $pays_id=$this->requestAction("/pays/setpays/$key");
                $this->Payspage->create();
                $data['Payspage']['pay_id']=$pays_id;
                $data['Payspage']['pag_id']=$page_id;
                $data['Payspage']['nombre']=$value;
                $this->Payspage->save($data);
            }
        }
```

the error is

```
Error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded    
File: C:\wamp\www\pub\app\webroot\fb\base_facebook.php  
Line: 971
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this code `set_time_limit(1000000);` in your function php

Answer (score 3):

Your query looks big and the Facebook API is not always that fast. So,

- either change your [`set_time_limit`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) delay from 60 seconds to more in your PHP.ini file,
- or slice your query into smaller parts.

A bigger query isn't always better. Smaller queries would allow you to get first results as soon as possible and would let you process it earlier or notify the users about the progress (thinking to AJAX).